# Check if someone is using a remote desktop connection to a computer

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to check whether a computer is being used by a remote desktop connection from another computer or not.Is there anyway to do it in C#.

Comment: Please stop putting your question in bold! This is considered rude and should be avoided on StackOverflow.

Comment: sorry.won't repeat next time

Answer (score 0):

[`WTSEnumerateSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the Win32 API to use.

Once you've found the right [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.wtsenumeratesessions) signature for calling it, you can look at the names of the windows stations returned